# Failed to logout using cron

Tags: 22.04, cron

I am trying to log off using editing `crontab -e` with the command

```
* * * * * gnome-session-quit
```

However, after one minute it is not asking or going for logout. Can anyone help me why is this the case?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Please add more context of what you are trying to to do. You may have to add the full path of the program you want to run in crontab, such as `/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit`.

Comment: `gnome-session-quit` probably needs to connect to an active DBUS session - see for example [How to use gnome-session-save from cron?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19195/how-to-use-gnome-session-save-from-cron)

Comment: @user68186 Thank you very much :) I am using version 22.04 and wanted to logout like after a minute. I tried using full path but it doesn't work still.